`marginaleffects::plot_comparisons()` for time-split survival data
Suppose I'm interested in estimating the effect of a binary variable for survival data as a hazard ratio. Before doing so, I want to split the observation period into two periods and estimate the effects in each of these. This can be done by using survSplit() as here:
library(dplyr)
library(survival)

dat <- survSplit(Surv(time, status == 1) ~ ., cut=c(0, 10, 200), episode = "interval", data = aml) |>
  as_tibble() |>
  mutate(interval = factor(interval))

cox <- coxph(Surv(tstart, time, event == 1) ~ x*interval, data = dat)
summary(cox)

#                            coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)
# xNonmaintained            1.4979    4.4724   1.1199  1.338    0.181
# interval3                     NA        NA   0.0000     NA       NA
# xNonmaintained:interval3 -0.7756    0.4604   1.2661 -0.613    0.540
# 
#                          exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
# xNonmaintained              4.4724     0.2236    0.4981    40.160
# interval3                       NA         NA        NA        NA
# xNonmaintained:interval3    0.4604     2.1719    0.0385     5.506

The model is overparameterized as the main effect of interval isn't estimable but this isn't an issue as I'm only interested in the effect of x and the interaction.
Now I wish to plot the two hazard ratios using marginaleffects::plot_comparisons using this code:
library(marginaleffects)
plot_comparisons(cox, variables = "x", condition = "interval", type = "lp", transform = "exp")

However, the resulting plot is missing confidence intervals but correctly calculates the hazard ratios. Is this is a bug or should I be doing something differently? I know I can circumvent this by having x as a numeric variable and using ~ x + x:interval but I'm not interested in taking this route.

My guess is that the problem is precisely because the model is overparameterized. vcov(cox) gives a column of 0s, and coef(cox) gives a NA element. marginaleffects is not setup internally to handle such situation, because the proper approach to computing standard errors with numerical differentiation is not self-evident. Many different problems could lead to NAs in many different kinds of models, and we can't handle them all, so it's safer to return NA as SE.

@Vincent: Thanks for the response. Yeah, that must be the case. I found a more manual way around it: remove the NAs of cox$coefficients and the corresponding rows/columns of cox$var. Then use hypotheses() to calculate the linear combinations with confidence intervals and manually do the plotting.
